# Add target='_blank' to all file links per default selected via link browser

Tags: typo3

I tried to solve it via the following way (found that as examples), but it has no effect in my Typo3 10 instance. I also find nothing about it in the current Typo3 10 docs about how to define the default target for linked files via link browser in Typo3 10. The following doesn't work:

```
RTE {
  default {
    preset = default
    classesAnchor {
      file {
        class = download
        type = file
        titleText = Open or download file in new window
        target = _blank
      }
    }
  }
}
```

AND:

```
TCEMAIN {
  linkHandler {
    file.addParams = onclick = "jumpToUrl('?act=file&linkAttributes[target]=_blank&linkAttributes[title]=Open or download file in new window&linkAttributes[class]=download');return false;"
    url.addParams = onclick = "jumpToUrl('?act=url&linkAttributes[target]=_blank&linkAttributes[title]=Open external link in new window&linkAttributes[class]=external-link');return false;"
    mail.addParams = onclick = "jumpToUrl('?act=mail&linkAttributes[title]=Send email&linkAttributes[class]=mail');return false;"
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to solve it via the mentioned way (found that as examples), but it has no effect in my Typo3 10 instance. I also find nothing about it in the current Typo3 10 docs.

Comment: Please explain that _in your question post_. :)

Comment: There's missing a closing bracket... And `TCEMAIN` should not be a subkey of `RTE` but on top-level.

Comment: That was just a copy/paste typo, in fact it does not work at all.